# Keep last x version of folders in every selected directory

Tags: powershell

I would like to somehow keep the last x amount of directories in the selected directory.

Ie. directory structure:
d:\test\

- a

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
- b

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
- c

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
- d

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4

CASE 1: If I give this: d:\test or d:\test\* with 2 last versions then the result should be:

- c

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
- d

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4

CASE 2: If I give this: d:\test\*\* with 2 last versions then the result should be:

- a

  - 3
  - 4
- b

  - 3
  - 4
- c

  - 3
  - 4
- d

  - 3
  - 4

CASE 3: If I give this: d:\test\*\*\* with 2 last versions then similarly to the previous case, the parents need to stay and only the subfolders need to be removed.

Until now I've found this:
`Get-ChildItem -Path D:\test -Directory | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -SkipLast 2 | Remove-Item`

This does work for case 1, but not for cases 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I've found a version that seems to work with all cases, but I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do this. Here is my version:

```
$group_dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Force | Group-Object -Property Parent

foreach ($group_dir in $group_dirs) {
    $group_dir.Group | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -SkipLast $leftCount | Remove-Item -Force
}
```